# ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT trigger from any constraint

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, upsert

I'm trying to trigger an UPSERT on any constraint but can't seem to find a syntax that would be similar to *`ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT (*)`*. I've attempted using cases to declare my specific constraint:

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT (
  CASE "@Type"
    WHEN 'user' THEN "Meta_User_Namespace"
    WHEN 'device' THEN "Meta_Device_Namespace"
    WHEN 'profile' THEN "Meta_UserProfile_Namespace"
    WHEN 'group' THEN "Meta_Group_Namespace"
  END
)
```

But I don't think this is an appropriate way of doing it and this syntax doesn't seem to work.

How should I solve this? I basically have this SP which handles meta for various table types. Rather than 4 separate tables linking to my meta I think just 4 columns with unique indexes should be adequate. Note that this SP acts as an UPSERT.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SetMeta" (
  "@Type"      VARCHAR(10),
  "@ID"        UUID,
  "@Namespace" VARCHAR(50),
  "@Data"      JSONB
)
RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO
    "Meta" AS um (
      "ID",
      "UserID",
      "UserProfileID",
      "DeviceID",
      "Namespace",
      "Data"
    )
  VALUES (
    UUID_GENERATE_V4(),
    CASE "@Type" WHEN 'user' THEN "@UserID" ELSE null END,
    CASE "@Type" WHEN 'profile' THEN "@UserProfileID" ELSE null END,
    CASE "@Type" WHEN 'device' THEN "@DeviceID" ELSE null END,
    CASE "@Type" WHEN 'group' THEN "@Namespace" ELSE null END,
    "@Namespace",
    "@Data"
  )
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT (
    CASE "@Type"
      WHEN 'user' THEN "Meta_User_Namespace"
      WHEN 'device' THEN "Meta_Device_Namespace"
      WHEN 'profile' THEN "Meta_UserProfile_Namespace"
      WHEN 'group' THEN "Meta_Group_Namespace"
    END
  )
  DO UPDATE SET
    "Data" = "@Data",
    "Updated" = NOW()
  WHERE
    (
      um."UserID" = "@UserID" OR
      um."UserProfileID" = "@UserProfileID" OR
      um."DeviceID" = "@DeviceID" OR
      um."GroupID" = "@GroupID"
    ) AND
    um."Namespace" = "@Namespace";
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL for that. Or use four different insert statements (btw: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth it)

Comment: Dynamic SQL? Like dynamic variables in place of my case statements?

Comment: I've started toying with using EXECUTE and changing the values in my statement ie: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SetUserMeta" (
  "@Type"      VARCHAR(10),
  "@ID"        UUID,
  "@Namespace" VARCHAR(50),
  "@Data"      JSONB
)
RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO
    "Meta" AS m (
      "ID",
      "'|| "@Type" ||'ID"
      "Namespace",
      "Data"
    )
  VALUES (
    UUID_GENERATE_V4(),
    "'|| "@ID" ||'" ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to trigger an UPSERT on any constraint but can't seem to find a syntax that would be similar to *`ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT (*)`*.

Just ***omit*** the optional conflict target clause `ON CONSTRAINT` to fire for *any* unique violation:

```
INSERT INTO "Meta" AS um ( ... )
VALUES ( ... )
ON CONFLICT                            -- that's all!
DO UPDATE SET ...
```

[Details in the manual on `INSERT`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

I would provide a working version of your function, but what you posted is inconsistent. `"@UserID"` is undefined, etc.

And use simple, unquoted, legal, lower-case identifiers everywhere in Postgres, like [@a_horse already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508178/on-conflict-on-constraint-trigger-from-any-constraint#comment76009918_44508178). (That includes parameter and variable names in SQL and PL/pgSQL functions.)

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)